# What is the maximum array size for Zarr?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, resources, constraints, zarr

I was not able to find information on any limits of `Zarr` arrays. Is there any practical limit on the size of `Zarr` arrays apart from the disk space? This is covering both: number of dimensions and size of each dimension.

Comment: do you have a size range in mind or is this just a theoretical question? we've worked with zarr stores on the order of a few terrabytes without much trouble... I imagine you'll start running into either memory bottlenecks or limits on the ability of your dask scheduler to track all the tasks before you start bumping into any hard constraints though...

Comment: As an example, a sparse array of about `1e12 x 1e12 x 1e6`. I'm trying to figure out a scaleable solution for objects with very large dimensionality, but also that have a mixed sparse-dense structure (overall sparse, but some dense regions in the array).

Comment: got it. are you looking at using [`sparse`](https://sparse.pydata.org/en/stable/)? I've never actually tried saving a sparse zarr array but I imagine this is the intended use case exactly :) I bet the xarray user group would also be a good place to ask for the current best practices around saving a massive sparse array

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelDelgado! I'm at an early stage of planning a specific workflow, and trying to assess if Zarr will impose some scale constraints down the line. For managing sparse arrays, I will probably use `sparse`.

Comment: As an additional option: empty chunks need not be written. For some types of sparse data this suffices to save space.